# VMWare Workstation MSI Failed Install Windows 7

Tags: installation, vmware-workstation

When attempting to install VMWare Workstation 6 (as well as when I attempted to install an evaluation version of 9), the installer fails with an error simplay stating that '~\vmware workstation.msi failed'. This is in 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: I suggest to move this question to superuser site as it is an installation problem of a software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that stopping after the temp directory gets created and running 'vmware workstation.msi' directly instead of using the already-running installer allowed me to finish the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Avast! antivirus installed?

That was the cause of my failed installation message. I tried deactivating it for some time and it didn't work. I had to totally uninstall it, install vmware and then reinstall the antivirus.

It won't work if you use the disable feature of the antivirus, you must completely uninstall it.